# Android server-client application session issue

Tags: android, session, https, client-server, sessionid

I am developing server client application on android and i am using session on server side of application but sometimes i lost my session on server. 
Ps: i use https connection on server.

I am using these to hold session:

- I am using single instance DefaultHttpClient and use it for all http requests.
- I use only httpPost method
- I use only https certificate:

  schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", sslSocketFactory, 443));
  ClientConnectionManager cm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, schemeRegistry);
- I save my cookies after all http requests:

  private void createSessionCookie(){

  ```
  List<Cookie> cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();

  if (! cookies.isEmpty()){

      CookieSyncManager.createInstance(ctx);
      CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();

      //sync all the cookies in the httpclient with the webview by generating cookie string
      for (Cookie cookie : cookies){

          Cookie sessionInfo = cookie;

          String cookieString = sessionInfo.getName() + "=" + sessionInfo.getValue() + "; domain=" + sessionInfo.getDomain();
          cookieManager.setCookie(UrlConstants.SERVICE_PRE_URL, cookieString);
          CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
      }
  }
  ```

  }

Even though i am doing these, i lose session.
Please help me to solve this problem,
Thanks for any advice 
Best Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not do anything with cookies manually, just create static `CookieStore` somewhere, assign it to the `HttpContext`, and use that context in your requests. Cookies will be saved and restored automagically.

These are your class members:

```
private static CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
private HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
private HttpPost post = new HttpPost("your url here");
```

And this part goes into the member function, which does the request:

```
HttpContext ctx = new BasicHttpContext();
ctx.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

HttpResponse result = httpclient.execute(post,ctx);
```

Comment: Do i have to use single instance HttpPost method?

Comment: No. You only need the single instance of `CookieStore`, but otherwise you may use as many different get/post requests as you like, as long as you pass the `HttpContext`, attached to the same `CookieStore` along with them.